# making a batchfile in autoit

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, autoit

i checked my file with

```
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Contents of the file:" & @CRLF & $sFileRead)
```

so i know i created the file successfully

but when i want to change it to `.bat`
by moving it into a junk `.bat` file (other people probably have a better way of doing it) i get an error.

```
$CMD = "move "$sFilePath" " & $jointpath & @CRLF
RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & $CMD)
```

i get

```
error: syntax error
```

here is the whole function:

```
Func makeJointBat()
    Local Const $sFilePath = _WinAPI_GetTempFileName(@TempDir)
    FileWrite($sFilePath, "you don't need to know what i wrote there")
    Local $hFileOpen = FileOpen($sFilePath, $FO_READ)
    Local $sFileRead = FileRead($hFileOpen)
    FileClose($hFileOpen)
    $CMD = "move "$sFilePath" " & $jointpath & @CRLF
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & $CMD)
EndFunc   ;==>makeJointBat
```

Comment: Try removing that `& @CRLF` at the end of the $CMD = ... command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that you seem to be opening the file two times:
Once when creating it, then again when reading it.

However, you are only closing it once.

Adding a `FileClose` between the `FileWrite` and the `FileOpen` might help
with the problem.